# time type field getting bad default datetime if it is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Terrible title, but this is what I have:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.3p194 :001 > Product
 => Product(id: integer, name: string, date: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, end_time: datetime, start_time: time) 
1.9.3p194 :002 > p = Product.new
 => #<Product id: nil, name: nil, date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, end_time: nil, start_time: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :003 > p.start_time = "foo"
 => "foo" 
1.9.3p194 :004 > p.start_time
 => 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

I wouldn't expect an invalid time to parse into a valid one. This is causing me issues with validations from form submissions.

This is somewhat related: [Rails 3 - Validation for Time existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371519/rails-3-validation-for-time-existance)

And leads to this issue in github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6045

I tried eye tracing the code, but nothing pops out at me except that the "foo" shouldn't parse and it should return nil.

EDIT: I created a sample app that displays this exact behavior https://github.com/danbeaulieu/test-app

But really it's just a bare bones app with a single model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) which validates dates, times and datetimes .

Then in your model you can do

```
validates_time :start_time
```

OR have a look at my [GIST](https://gist.github.com/3621130) to handle default date validation

Comment: Aha, yes, I am exactly trying to use that gem, however, by the time the field is validated, it has already been turned into a valid (though incorrect) datetime.

Comment: Converting to datetime is a nice  approach and i will prefer it over using this gem as the activerecord is much more capable of handling validations.  If u have the hard line of storing only the time go for the gem.  otherwise datetime ---> time conversion for UI won't be a big job :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm not converting anything, some piece of rails is converting "foo" -> "2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC". Regardless of validations the behavior above from my console session seems illogical. Either I am doing something wrong or there is a bug.

Comment: @Dan.StackOverflow the date that you are seeing is the default date that get's stored by rails in the database, if the attributes provided are not as expected.  I have created a GIST for  custom validates for such default scenarious.  i hope it helps https://gist.github.com/3621130

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate your patience. However, that datetime is still a valid value, so it's difficult to call it invalid. Seems like a bug to me if this is the solution.

Comment: Thanks, yeah we should not call it inValid but a default value.  So if the user provides a string ("Foo") the default date gets stored as (Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 2000) and the above [GIST](https://gist.github.com/3621130) if implemented rollsback when it finds the default value!
I hope my solution helped you.  Don't forget to vote up if it helped!